# Is the suspension of a countable collection of points in $\mathbb{R}$ a countable collection of circles?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am extremely new to topology and taking an algebraic topology course, and I need some help understanding the behavior of suspensions. The problem I am working on asks about the suspension of the subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ consisting of the sequence 1, 1/2, ... with the limit point 0 added. The main example I'm able to find of a suspension appears to turn a circle into the outer shell of a double-cone with the top and bottom points identified, but does that mean that a suspension generally "squeezes" the figure it starts with on its way up and down?

From what I can tell, the definition of a suspension implies to me that the suspension of a single point in $\mathbb{R}$ should be a circle, so the suspension of several or a countable collection of such points should then be a similarly-numbered collection of copies of $S^1$. Is this correct? And, if it is, would the circles in this case have 1, 1/2 ..., and 0 as their basepoints, or should they all somehow have the same basepoint somewhere?

Comment: Well, a countable collection of circles sounds like a rather non-path-connected space, and the suspension is connected, so probably no!

Comment: That's fine and all, but the collection of points in R is already non-path-connected, so, I don't really know how to deal with that

Comment: What I mean is that the suspension of anything is a path-connected space, but a "collection of circles" (if we take the description literally) is not a connected space. It follows that the question in your title has the obvious answer: no.

Comment: All right, that being the case, how does a suspension accomplish making a non-path-connected thing into a path-connected thing? I can't quite make sense of how it's done from the definition of apparently just crossing the space with I and identifying a couple of points.

Comment: Consider a diSCrete space consisting of two points and describe its suspension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to address everything in your question :

---

The suspension of a point is *not* a circle. Let's go back to the definition. The suspension of a space $X$ is:
$$S X = X \times [0,1] / \sim$$
where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation generated by $(x,0) \sim (y,0)$ and $(x,1) \sim (y,1)$ (for all $x,y \in X$). This definition, applied to a point, gives $S \{pt\} = \{pt\} \times [0,1] / \sim$ where the equivalence relation is actually trivial, and $S \{pt\} \cong [0,1]$ is just a segment.

---

The suspension of a "collection" (more formally, a disjoint union) is *not* the collection of the suspensions. In other words, for example if $X = \bigsqcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} X_n$ then $S X$ is not equal to $\bigsqcup S X_n$. As Mariano Suárez-Alvarez recommends, let's try to work out for example the collection of two points $X = \{a,b\}$. Then $S X = \{a,b\} \times [0,1] / \sim$ and in fact this is homeomorphic to two segments *connected at their endpoints*: the collapsed points $X \times \{0\}$ and $X \times \{1\}$.

[image: Suspension of two points]

More generally it's always the case that the suspension is path-connected (and therefore connected); indeed if $[x,t] \in S X$, there exists a path between $[x,t]$ and $[x,0] = [X \times \{0\}]$.

---

Finally the subspace $X = \{1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \dots\} \cup \{0\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is not (topologically) the disjoint union of its components. Indeed, any neighborhood of $0$ has to contain an infinite number of points -- this wouldn't be the case if the topology was that of the disjoint union. Similarly, the suspension is more complicated than the suspension of a disjoint union of a countable number of points (which would be homotopically equivalent to a countably infinite wedge sum of circles). Based on what I wrote before, try to compute it now.

---

PS: Regarding base points: there is a priori no canonical base point on a suspension. There would be two candidates (the two collapsed subspaces). On the other hand, the *reduced* suspension $\Sigma X$ is homotopically equivalent to the suspension (in good cases only! eg. CW complexes. this isn't the case here), and it has a canonical base point.

Comment: Given your last comment about the reduced suspension being homotopy equivalent to the full suspension, is this true in all cases? It feels like the reduced suspension of the space in the OP (with base point $0$) is homeomorphic to the Hawaiian earings (I could be wrong here) whereas the full suspensions appears to have a countably generated fundamental group (one generator for each non-zero point in the base space). I think this is because the space in the OP isn't a CW complex.

Comment: @DanielRust: Aah yes you're probably right. I have this terrible habit of thinking that everything is a CW complex. It does look like the reduced suspension is the Hawaiian earring, but the normal suspension isn't.

Comment: Thank you very much! So if I am looking to create a fundamental group for this object, I could arbitrarily pick the collapsed space at 0 as a basepoint to use?

Comment: @Xindaris: It's path connected, so yes.